# How do i display stuff on My Window on Windows using directx

Tags: windows, directx

Hello i know how to create a window using directx, but how do i display stuff on that window instead of having a totally white and blank window

Comment: You can follow Microsoft official tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dgetstarted/building-your-first-directx-app or google for "directx tutorial"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post is missing a few key details:

- What version of DirectX?
- Are you using classic Win32 development or UWP?
- What language? C++? C#?

If you are new to DirectX, then you should start with **DirectX 11**. For Win32 classic application development in C++ you can the official [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/direct3dgetstarted/building-your-first-directx-app) tutorial mentioned in the comments above. For UWP, see [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/tutorial--create-your-first-uwp-directx-game) instead.

See also [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/anatomy-of-direct3d-11-create-device/) and [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/direct3d).

> You may also want to take a look at the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started) and [these VS templates](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates).

If you are looking to render 'presentation-style' graphics rather than 3D, then you may want to take a look at [Direct2D](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/direct2d/direct2d-portal).